# PowerShell: Why does this "foreach" code run forever?

Tags: powershell

I am using the following PS script to rename(add a prefix to each file) a batch of files. The problem is that this script does not stop and keeps adding the prefix to each file like `some_prefix_some_prefix_...`. What is wrong with this script?

```
function addPrefix ($dirPath, $prefix, $filter) {
   Get-ChildItem $dirPath -Filter $filter -Recurse  | % {
        $newNmae = $prefix + $_.Name
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newNmae
   }
    }

addPrefix "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\tmp" "some_prefix_" "*.jpg"
```

The "tmp" directory structure as follows↓

```
tmp
 |--1
 |  |-file1
 |  |-file2
 |  |-file3
 |  |   :
 |
 |--2
 |--3
 |--4
 |--5
```

Each directory 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 contains 5,000 files.

Comment: my guess is that every renamed file  is considered a new file, I would suggest you hold all files (along with path) into a variable and rename them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works now.

Comment: As a sidenote : `foreach` is faster and more memory consuming, `Foreach-Object` is *quite* the opposite (see http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object.aspx)